# Порядок удаления элементов списка в python.

Tags: python

В нижеприведенном коде я создаю список экземпляров класса A, а потом удаляю его.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __del__(self):
        print self.val,

object_list = [A(i) for i in range(5)]
del object_list
```

Для того, чтобы было понятно в каком порядке удаляются элементы, я добавил print в метод  `__del__`.
Я ожидал увидеть вывод
    0 1 2 3 4
т.к. в [документации](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) (если я правильно понимаю) написано, что удаление списка объектов будет выполняться по очереди слева направо.

Вывод в итоге такой:
    4 3 2 1 0

Я так понимаю, что все-таки в документации описан случай, когда выражении del через запятую перечислено несколько объектов и тогда они удаляются действительно слева направо. Но с переданным списком видимо инструкция ведет себя не так. Был бы крайне благодарен, если бы кто-то ткнул мне в место документации или любой книге, где объясняется порядок удаления элементов из списка при удалении этого самого списка.

У меня python 2.6

**upd.** Кстати я все-таки нашел на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205102/calling-del-on-a-list) абсолютно такой же вопрос, раньше как ни искал, я на него не наткнулся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [`__del__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) - это метод, вызывающийся в
> случае, если на соответствующий объект
> не остается ссылок.

Единственная гарантия, которую дает нам вызов `del list` или `del list[:]` - это то, что количество ссылок на элементы списка *уменьшатся на 1* (в первом случае также уменьшится на 1 количество ссылок на сам объект `list`).

Порядок вызова `__del__` на элементах определяется **implementation-specific** поведением `del list`, и, вообще говоря, порядок обхода элементов в этом методе нигде не специфицирован.

Таким образом, в зависимости от реализации элементы вызовы `__del__` могут происходить как в порядке `4 3 2 1 0`, так и в порядке `0 1 2 3 4`.

---

Если добавить чуть больше конкретики, то в реализации `CPython` обратный обход элементов объясняется отсутствием `thrashing'a` **в одном конкретном случае** - `create` и немедленный `release` элементов огромного списка.

*Ниже приведен фрагмент функции `list_dealloc` в `listobject.c` в реализации `CPython`.*

> ```
>     /* Do it backwards, for Christian Tismer.
>        There's a simple test case where somehow this reduces
>        thrashing when a *very* large list is created and
>        immediately deleted. */
> ```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ, я посмотрел в исходник и успокоился. Думал, что это наверное нигде не документировано, но не был уверен. 
Правда я так и не понял, почему при создании-удалении с конца огромного списка уменьшится занимание памяти, но разработчикам интерпретатора виднее.